# efficient way on windows to obtain the path as is in the file system

Tags: winapi, filesystems

Windows file system is case insensitive. When I have a file path I would like the cases to be exactly as they are in the file system. Right now I am using the following code to make sure of this:

```
std::vector<std::wstring> directories;
boost::split(directories, api, is_any_delimiter);

size_t i = 0;
std::wstring path;

if (hasWindowsDriverLetter())
{
    path += directories[i++];
}

std::wstring delimiter(L"\\");

for (;i < directories.size(); ++i)
{
    std::wstring search = path + delimiter + directories[i];

    WIN32_FIND_DATAW FindFileData;
    HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFileW(search.c_str(), &FindFileData);
    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        path = search;
        continue;
    }

    path += delimiter + FindFileData.cFileName;
    ::FindClose(hFind);
}
```

My function is in performance sensitive place - is there more efficient way to do this?

Note: `GetLongPathNameW` does not do the trick.

Comment: Why do you need this, if you know Windows does not care about the original case?

Comment: because I need the text representation of the path as string and I sue it to identify files in another case-sensitive system

Comment: You can't speed up `FindFirstFile()`, but you can speed up the rest of the code by not using `split()` or building up the new `path` dynamically. Iterate through the original `api` path directly instead. Each time you encounter a delimiter, temporarily replace it with `\0` and call `FindFirstFile()` using the original `api` string, then restore the delimiter and replace everything between that delimiter and the last delimiter with the result that was found. As long as case changes do not result in substrings of different sizes, you don't need to perform any memory allocations.

Comment: And if `FindFirstFile()` files, stop searching since you will not be able to get any further results from that point onward.

Comment: Why not track the files in a case-insensitive manner, or convert them to a common case before tracking them?

Comment: @RemyLebeau It is 3rdparty system that I do not have control over

Comment: @RemyLebeau - using \0 will be possible only if the size of the searched directory is the same, which might not be true if the offered path is 8.3 format

Comment: I think you do not understand what I was describing.  Substituting in `\0` while iterating the string will work just fine.  I will write up an example when I have some more time.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sorry, my bad, I believe I got it now

Comment: I posted an example.  Might need some tweaking, but you should get the jist of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
std::wstring::iterator GetIteratorAfterRoot(std::wstring &str)
{
    std::wstring::iterator iter = str.begin();

    wchar_t *tmp = str.c_str();
    wchar_t *tmp2;
    if (PathCchSkipRoot(tmp, &tmp2) == S_OK)
        iter += std::distance(tmp, tmp2);

    return iter;
}
```

```
std::wstring api = ...;

std::wstring start = GetIteratorAfterRoot(api);
std::wstring end = api.end();

WIN32_FIND_DATAW FindFileData;
HANDLE hFind;

bool finished = false;
while (start != end)
{
    std::wstring::iterator found = std::find_if(start, end, is_any_delimiter); 

    if (found != end)
    {
        wchar_t delim = *found;
        *found = L'\0';
        hFind = FindFirstFileW(api.c_str(), &FindFileData);
        *found = delim;
    }
    else
    {
        finished = true;
        hFind = FindFirstFileW(api.c_str(), &FindFileData);
    }

    if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        ::FindClose(hFind);

        std::wstring::difference_type SearchLength = std::distance(start, found);
        int FileNameLength = lstrlenW(FindFileData.cFileName);

        if (SearchLength != FileNameLength)
        {
            // string length is changing...

            if (finished)
            {
                api.replace(start, found, FindFileData.cFileName);
                break;
            }

            std::wstring::difference_type SearchOffset = std::distance(api.begin(), start);
            api.replace(start, found, FindFileData.cFileName);
            start = api.begin() + (SearchOffset + FileNameLength + 1);
            end = api.end();

            continue;
        }

        // string length not changing, copy new name inlined...

        // not sure if std::wstring::replace() is smart enough to do an
        // inline copy if the two lengths match, so using std::copy instead...

        //api.replace(start, found, FindFileData.cFileName); 
        std::copy(FindFileData.cFileName, &FindFileData.cFileName[FileNameLength], start); 
    }

    if (finished)
        break;

    start = found + 1;
}
```